# What kind of server and setup does Magento CE 1.7 single store need to run efficiently with 400K+ products in DB

Tags: configuration, extensions, server-setup

- CE
- 400+ SKU's
- All simple products (books)
- one single image (book vocer)
- No need for "compare products"
- Low traffic

What about server (hardware and config)?
What about software aid (SOLR, Varnish, etc)

What I am trying to achieve is a reasonably fast front-end page delivery

Answer (score 1):

There can't be a straight answer to your question. You need solid numbers to benchmark against.
For example:

*Given 3 concurrent visitors browsing and 1 customer placing an order, the average load time for a category page should be 0.8 seconds or faster.*

Also, you should specify the Magento and the PHP version you will be using in addition to the MySQL server variant (Mysql? Percona? MariaDB?) and version.

That said, I think you should be fine using a medium dedicated (VM) server if the stack configuration is tuned well. You might want to consider using a PHP side full page cache though.